# How to delete a row from ng-grid based on index value

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I am having a basic grid ,whose data is coming from an external JSON file

```
[{"Name":"ABC","Age":10},{"Name":"PQR","Age":20},{"Name":"XYZ","Age":30}]
```

I want something like every row should have a unique index ,Whenever I add some row(for now m adding some random row to it)

```
$scope.addRow = function() {
    $scope.myData.push($scope.myData[Math.floor((Math.random() * $scope.myData.length) + 1)])
  }
```

it should increment index value everytime and I want some text box to be displayed below the grid in which i should be able to put multiple index values for the rows that are no more needed in the grid and when I click a delete button it should remove the rows with the indexes shown in that textbox.
Please tell me how can I achieve this functionality with some demo.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Create new function for remove and pass "unique index" which you will get from foreach.

From this remove function you can remove element by

$scope.myData.splice( index, 1 );

May be It will work.....

Answer (score 0):

if you already know the index of the value.

$scope.myData.splice(index, 1);